# Want to fetch first three character from the String

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, jsr223

I have use case in JMeter JSR223 where I want to fetch First three characters from a String
Example given Below
def randomPrefix = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6)

vars.put("Trailer_ID", TrailerId)

Output: Trailer_ID : QlWBvp

I want to fetch only QlW

Comment: Check the comment here https://community.broadcom.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=757200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [String.take() function](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#take(int))

```
def foo = vars.get('Trailer_ID').take(3)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)